# how to add success key in web api json array C# web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, webapi2

[Route("api/GetMenuBykidnew")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMenuBykidnew(int kid, string Username)
        {

```
        ApiBusiness ApiBus = new ApiBusiness();

        var result = ApiBus.GetKitchenMenubyKitchennew(kid, Username);
        return result;

    }
```

[
    {
        "CartId": 1016,
        "OrderId": 124,
        "Username": "7887878787",
        "KitchenId": null,
        "CartAddedDate": "2020-01-21T00:00:00",
        "MenuId": 2055,
        "MenuName": "Veg Fried Rice",
        "MenuVariantId": 2055,
        "Rate": 91,
        "Quantity": 4,
        "ListPrice": 91,
        "ListGST": 4.55,
        "ListPacking": 5,
        "TotalPrice": 100.55,
        "MenuStatus": 0
    }
]

Expected result

success:[
    {
        "CartId": 1016,
        "OrderId": 124,
        "Username": "8892696780",
        "KitchenId": null,
        "CartAddedDate": "2020-01-21T00:00:00",
        "MenuId": 2055,
        "MenuName": "Veg Fried Rice",
        "MenuVariantId": 2055,
        "Rate": 91,
        "Quantity": 4,
        "ListPrice": 91,
        "ListGST": 4.55,
        "ListPacking": 5,
        "TotalPrice": 100.55,
        "MenuStatus": 0
    }
]

Comment: change  return result; with return Ok(new {success: result });

Comment: [Route("api/GetMenuBykidnew")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMenuBykidnew(int kid, string Username)
        {

            ApiBusiness ApiBus = new ApiBusiness();

            var result = ApiBus.GetKitchenMenubyKitchennew(kid, Username);
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JArray.FromObject(result).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };


        }

Comment: You dont need serialize just use this replace return result; with return Ok(new {success = result });